# Code review/improvements - my code works, but I want to ask if there is a better solution - where can I ask this type of question?

Tags: discussion, support, code-review-se

My code works, but I would like to ask if:

- is it a good solutions
- is it not too slow
- is it following best practices
- is there a better/shorter/clearer code/solution
- is this solution introducing hidden bugs?

Or I just want to learn from the community.

Where should I ask this type of question?
Stack Overflow says "We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed."

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Wasn't aware of codereview.stackexchange.com :) Live and learn... thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in comments. [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) is the place you want to go. But before you jump for joy now, be aware that we have [some (seemingly) "unintuitive" rules](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

These rules have been summed up and explained multiple times throughout multiple meta-sites and loads of comments, but still:

> Simply ask yourself the following questions. To be on-topic the answer
> must be "yes" to all questions:
>
> - Is code included directly in my question? (See Make sure you include your code in your question below.)
> - Am I an owner or maintainer of the code?
> - Is it actual code from a project rather than pseudo-code or example code?
> - Do I want the code to be good code? (i.e. not code-golfing, obfuscation, or similar)
> - To the best of my knowledge, does the code work?
> - Do I want feedback about any or all facets of the code?

And last but not least, there's even a comprehensive meta q&a about [getting the most value out of codereview.](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions)

With that said, if you are uncertain about how things work or whether your code is on-topic: You're welcome to ask on the [on-site meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) or ask codereview users in [the 2nd monitor](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)